# Need to change Value of Lable inside Cell on button touch event

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using custom cellview with table view.
Label is added in cell view and buttons are added programmatically 
on button action:@selector I need to change value of label with that cell but have no clue how to do this.

**TagCell.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgCellImage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblCellDate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblCellLocation;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtCellTag;
```

**TagViewController.m**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    TagCell *cell = (TagCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TagCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        //cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

UIImage *DatebuttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"calendar_icon.png"];

    UIButton *DateButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    DateButton.tag = imgID;
    DateButton.frame = CGRectMake(200.0f, 10.0f, 20.0f, 20.0f);
    [DateButton setImage:DatebuttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [DateButton addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(PickDate:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [cell addSubview:DateButton];
}

-(void)PickDate:(id) sender
{
    UIButton *clicked = (UIButton *) sender;

    currentrow = (int )clicked.tag;
    SACalendar *calendar = [[SACalendar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 500) scrollDirection:ScrollDirectionVertical
                                              pagingEnabled:NO];
    calendar.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:calendar];

}
```

Now after selecting date I need it to set in label of that cell
but not able to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand very well what you are trying to do but you can access Outlets in cell with

```
TagCell *cell = (TagCell *)[self.yourTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.yourLabel.text = @"your text";
```

You can get the relative indexPath in your -(void)PickDate:(id)sender with

```
TagCell *cell = (TagCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.yourTableView indexPathForCell:Cell];
```

I hope it's help!

Comment: **YES YES it help a lot lot. Thank you so much brother.**

I am trying to give date picker ability via calendar in table cell.

idk exact way so doing it like that.

But you Fix this bro, Thank you so so much.

Comment: @SiddharthChauhan Accept the answer if helped you.It would help futute readers.